# How to get this jQuary script working?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I've searched for it, but I just getting more confused.

I want to use this script to show a menubar after scrolling down 200px:
https://redvinestudio.com/how-to-make-a-menu-fade-in-on-scroll-using-jquery/

I set the CSS witch is self explained - to put in the custom.css

Than I put this in the **functions.php** (I'm using a child theme):

```
function add_latest_jquery() {
   if ( !is_admin() ) {
      wp_deregister_script('jquery');
      wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js', false);
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   }
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts ', 'add_latest_jquery');
```

I'm not sure if that's right, because of the `!is_admin()`

And I just don't know where and how to put the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){                          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('#menu').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#menu').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh okay.. I think I solved it.

I put the script in the **header.php** (I think "into the loop" as they say?) just behind the opening `<header>`-tag:

```
<body>
<header>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){                          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('#menu').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#menu').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```